# Executing a pipe line command with findstr

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, findstr

I am trying to get the name of a file containing a particular string. The following command does that.

```
dir /a:-D /b | findstr /i "fileName.jar"
```

I'm trying to run it through a bat file using the following code.

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a:-D /b | findstr /i "fileName.jar"') do set "batToolDir=%%a"
```

But I am getting the below error.

```
| was unexpected at this time.
```

I need to get the name of the file containing a certain string. How can I achieve this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"below error" ??

What you need is to escape the `|` to tell `cmd` that the pipe is part of the command to be executed, not of the `for`. You need to do this with all redirectors.

The escape character is `^`, so substitute `^|` for `|` within the parentheses. ANy such awkwardness, try inserting `^` before the character causing the problem...